# Issue with Bash variables

Tags: bash, variables, naming-conventions

I'm trying to make a code for finding the number and type of atoms from a file.

The file `B.txt` has few names of the atoms in it and is read to go into the specific atom directory. The file input has the values of the positions and atom types in it. But I cannot store the name of atom as `atom_1, atom_2, atom_3` etc..
If I change the atom_$i to atom, then the code works perfectly.

I expect the **output** to be `atom_1=X,numberofatoms_1=100, atom_2=Y, numberofatoms_2=200` etc and so on.

> The error is something like:
>    2(total number of types of atoms)
>    bash: atom_1=x: command not found

```
cd ~/A/
cat ~/A/B.txt | while read line
do
        cd folder_"$line"
        sed -n 6p input> temp1.txt
        sed -n 7p input > temp2.txt
        atoms=  wc -w < temp1.txt > junk  
        #echo ${atoms}
        typeset -i atoms=$(cat junk)
        i=1
        numberofatoms=0
        echo ${atoms}
        while [ $i -le $atoms ]
        do
                ptri=$( echo "scale=2; $i" | bc)
                atom="$(cat temp1.txt | sed -n '1p'| cut -d' ' -f$ptri)" > junk
                echo $atom

                # next section is the code for counting the total number of atomsin the system
                noa=$(cat temp2.txt | sed -n '1p'| cut -d' ' -f$ptri)
                numberofatoms_$i=$(( $numberofatoms + $noa ))
                i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        echo "number of atoms = " $numberofatoms
cd ..
rm junk
rm temp1
rm temp2
```

done

Comment: The command `wc -w < temp1.txt > junk` stores the result of the `wc` into a file named _junk_.  The expression `$(cat junk)` tries to interpret the content of this file as a command and run it. Of course there is no command of this name, and so you get an error message.

Comment: Run your code with `-x`, so you can see exactly, what is going on.

Comment: Please provide an example of an input file and what you want the output to look like. Also, [format for readability](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).